# Async / await problem, The Async / await function is returning true before the value is placed in the new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await, es6-promise

I am creating a multiple image file upload using firebase and react-typescript. My main problem is with async/await. I have a function called `uploadFiles` which will save the downloaded URLs into my `URLs` state. But the problem is `uploadFiles` returning true while the URLs are still loading to set into the state.

My expectation is until `setUrls` state new values are placed into the `setUrls` state the Async / await will not return true.

I have explained in the video also, https://youtu.be/t6JqasRCPRM

Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-pine-tdv3wf?file=/src/AddProduct.tsx:2777-2941

The main problem is here: `setURLs` are taking time to set into the state.

```
  async () => {
    await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURLs: any) => {
         setURLs((prevState: any) => [...prevState, downloadURLs])
         console.log("2 File available at", downloadURLs);
});
```

Also, another problem is that promise is returning true while the URLs are still loading to set into the state.

```
   try {
            await Promise.all(promises);
            setSuccess(true);
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            return false;
        }
```

`UploadFiles` function:

```
 const uploadFiles = async (files: any) => {

        const promises: any = []
        files.map((file: any) => {

            const sotrageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);
            const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(sotrageRef, file);
            promises.push(uploadTask)
            uploadTask.on(
                "state_changed",
                (snapshot: any) => {
                    const prog = Math.round(
                        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                    );
                    setProgress(prog);
                },
                (error: any) => console.log(error),
                async () => {
                    await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURLs: any) => {
                        setURLs((prevState: any) => [...prevState, downloadURLs])
                        console.log("2 File available at", downloadURLs);

                    });
                }
            );


        })

        try {
            await Promise.all(promises);
            setSuccess(true);
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

`uploadWasSuccessful` is returning true I want until the setURls is available my if statement will not go to the next step.

```
  const handleProductSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const uploadWasSuccessful: any = await uploadFiles(images) // returning true but the urls are still loading.
        console.log('uploadWasSuccessful', uploadWasSuccessful);
        console.log('Success', success);

        if (uploadWasSuccessful) {
            const newProductValue = { ...productValue, URLs }
            console.log(newProductValue, 'productValue');
        }

    }
```

Comment: `uploadTask` is not a promise, so you are deceiving yourself when you push it into a `promises` array.

Comment: @trincot so I need to remove the promises?

Answer (score 0):

The setSuccess(true) call here is not asynchronous. This means its running immediately before the promises are resolved. Add await here to wait for the promises to resolve above.

```
try {
            await Promise.all(promises);
            await setSuccess(true); //await
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            return false;
        }
```

also make the uploads promises by including await here:

```
 const sotrageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);
            const uploadTask = await uploadBytesResumable(sotrageRef, file); //added await
            await promises.push(uploadTask) //added await
```

Comment: ` const sotrageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);
            const uploadTask = await uploadBytesResumable(sotrageRef, file); //added await
            await promises.push(uploadTask)` it gives me error for using await before promise

Answer (score 0):

The trick I normally use is that the `uploadTask` it itself a promise already, so you can `await` it or chain its `then`, and just skip the approach with (at least) the third callback:

```
const uploadFiles = async (files: any) => {

  const promises: any = []
  files.map((file: any) => {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
    const urlTask = uploadTask.then(() => storageRef.getDownloadURL); // 
    promises.push(urlTask); // 
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot: any) => {
        const prog = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );
        setProgress(prog);
      },
      (error: any) => console.log(error),
      () => { } // 
    );
  })

  try {
    const downloadURLs = await Promise.all(promises); // 
    setURLs(downloadURLs); // 
    setSuccess(true);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: sir, `downloadURLs` is returning undefined